# Adding colours (related to magnitude) to 3dimensional quiver plots. [Magnetic Field]

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, colors, 3d

Am having trouble with 3D quiver plots. Specifically in relation to the strength of the 'field' or vector at that point. So far can only change colours of all arrows and not have the magnitude scale TOGETHER with the colours.

Anyone got any solutions? (Problem code provided)

```
Rx = (bx+tx+px+lx)
Ry = (by+ty+py+ly)
Rz = (bz+tz+pz+lz)                      #Resultant Field
ax = plt.figure().gca(projection='3d')

ax.quiver(x,y,z,Rx,Ry,Rz,length=2.0,cmap='Reds',
arrow_length_ratio=0.5,pivot='middle',normalize=False) 
#This is the main PROBLEM part of the code, refuses colour gradient plotting!!

plt.title('Magnetic field')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.show()
```